# Is it possible to redirect traffic sent to https://ip to http://ip?

Tags: http, ubuntu, https, server, ubuntu-16.04

I've seen a lot of solution for redirecting a webserver, but I have a Ubuntu server that is running an application, not over a url.  I'd like to redirect requests from https://ip to http://ip, without setting up a domain for this server.

I want the response from http://ip to be returned when https://ip is queried.

I've tried using iptables to redirect traffic from port 443 to 80, but this did not work as requests to https://ip could not get a response.

I also tried using [firewall-cmd](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-firewalld-on-centos-7) to allow traffic on port 443, but this did not work either.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

By changing the port from 443 to 80, traffic doesn't magically change from HTTP to HTTPS. You can see the port number as a house number and the protocol as a secret knock to get in.

You need to have a service running (who knows the secret knock) on port (house number) 80, which understands the HTTPS protocol (the secret knock).